# jquery vertical tab, jumping to top of the page, how to stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my  demo link: http://www.bajistech.info/tiltindicators.html

I have to create specific link for each tab

```
 function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
     }
    $(document).ready(function(){

    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        //$('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
```

// no need for each loop
            $('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function() {

```
            showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
        });
        //});
        if(window.location.hash) 
        // if hash found then load the tab from Hash id
        {
           showSection( window.location.hash);// to get the div id
        }
        else // if no hash found then default first tab is opened
        {
            $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to handle href when click, add this code to your JS:

```
$("#verticalNav li a").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: hi friend, thanks but i need to show tab id also like: tiltindicators.html#TiltWatch-Plus1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

```
$('ul#verticalNav li a').click(function(){
return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed Rashid, thanks, i need to create the link also like :tiltindicators.html#TiltWatch-Plus1.